# Trouble understanding Java threads

Tags: java

I learned about multiprocessing from Python and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding Java's approach.  In Python, I can say I want a pool of 4 processes and then send a bunch of work to my program and it'll work on 4 items at a time.  I realized, with Java, I need to use threads to achieve this same task and it seems to be working really really well so far.

But.. unlike in Python, my cpu(s) aren't getting 100% utilization (they are about 70-80%) and I suspect it's the way I'm creating threads (code is the same between Python/Java and processes are independent). In Java, I'm not sure how to create one thread so I create a thread for every item in a list I want to process, like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        Runnable task = new MyRunnable(10000000L + i);
        Thread worker = new Thread(task);
        // We can set the name of the thread
        worker.setName(String.valueOf(i));
        // Start the thread, never call method run() direct
        worker.start();
        // Remember the thread for later usage
        threads.add(worker);
    }
```

I took it from [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#threads). My question is this the correct way to launch threads or is there a way to have Java itself manage the number of threads so it's optimal? I want my code to run as fast as possible and I'm trying to understand how to tell and resolve any issues that maybe arising from too many threads being created.

This is not a major issue, just curious to how it works under the Java hood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the Java [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) API. See this [article](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/09/java-concurrency-part-7-executors-and-thread-pools/), for example.

Although creating Threads is much 'cheaper' than it used to be, creating large numbers of threads (one per runnable as in your example) isn't the way to go - there's still an overhead in creating them, and you'll end up with too much context switching.

The Executor API allows you to create various types of thread pool for executing Runnable tasks, so you can reuse threads, flexibly manage the number that are created, and avoid the overhead of thread-per-runnable.

The Java threading model and the Python *threading* model (not multiprocessing) are really quite similar, incidentally. There isn't a Global Interpreter Lock as in Python, so there's usually less need to fork off multiple processes.

Comment: +1 Thank you so much. I had this feeling about threads but because I couldn't control the spawning of them(the way I was doing it) I couldn't hack around and test it more.  I think Executor is exactly what I can use to do this.  One other question(somewhat related), does executor manage a static number of threads or if there is excess capacity can exector automatically spawn(or let die) threads as needed?

Comment: Either is possible, depending on whether you create a fixed thread pool or a cached thread pool.

Answer (score 5):

You use an [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), the implementation of which handles a pool of threads, decides how many, and so forth. See [the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) for lots of examples.

In general, bare threads aren’t used in Java except for very simple things. Instead, there will be some higher-level API that receives your Runnable or Task and knows what to do.

Comment: +1.  Executors and ExecutorServices are the way to spread out tasks between cores.

Comment: Thanks so much Josh, I'll def. look deeper into executor and play around.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Thread is a "low level" API.

Depending on what you want to do, and the version of java you use, their is better solution.
If you use Java 7, and if your task allow it, you can use the fork/join framework : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

However, take a look at the java concurrency tutorial : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html